# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor. Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Lavender'. Why it is happening

Tags: color, backgrounds, gradient

I want to add a colour gradiant inner to outer from Lavender to white

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=11in,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\begin{document}
    
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue}

%for gradiant background this code below


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path [inner color=Lavender,outer color=White] (current page.north east)rectangle (current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}

{\fontsize{40}{20}\selectfont\textbf{\underline{Functional Equation Week: Problem 5}}}
        
\vspace*{1cm}
        
{\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont\textbf{Send me Your Answer!}}
\vspace*{1cm}
\end{center}
        
{\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont Find all functions $ f : \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that \[ x^2y^2 \left( f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y) \right)=3(x+y)f(x)f(y)\] holds for all reals $x$ and $y$}
        
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}  
{\fontsize{30}{30}\textbf{ONLY ELEMENTARY SOLUTIONS ALLOWED}}
        
\vspace{1cm}

{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont $$\boldsymbol{\sum \limits_{i=0}^{Creative} Math_i = Solving}$$}
        
\vspace{1cm}
        
\begin{mybox}\Huge{\begin{center}\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Solution $\to$}} \end{center}}\end{mybox}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

But when i am compiling this it is showing me

> ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor

> ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Lavender'.

> ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `White'.

Why it is happening. Tell me the correct code

Comment: Use `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}` before loading tikz (and you don't need to load xcolor, tikz is doing it).

Comment: Yes it worked...thanks...i wrote the xcolor package before tikz and it runs